# Multiple secret keys for encrypting cookies in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, encryption, cookies

I want to share some session data in cookie between two Ruby on Rails applications on the same domain but different subdomain. I know I can share the whole session between those applications by setting the cookie domain to `.maindomain.com` and setting the same `secret_key` for signing and encrypting the session but I don't want to allow one of the apps to "mess" with other app's session and especially I don't want to use the same `secret_key` in both apps.

Is there any possibility to use different secret key to sign and encrypt only one cookie (the one shared between the apps) and use the normal Rails `secret_key` for the session?

Comment: If anything you want to encrypt the session cookie as it prevents the user from tampering with the session. You might want to consider using a different session storage mechanism such as Memcached/Redis instead. There is a slight performance tradeoff but it does not have the same cross domain cookie issues.

Comment: I don't think the rack sessions middleware allows different secret keys for different cookies.